# How should I know if a motherboard support SEDs?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, encryption

[SED (Self Encrypting Drive)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption) are more and more owned due to the rise of SSD.

Most of the time this functionality is not used because most of the motherboards in the market don't have built-in support for Self Encrypting Drives (ATA password) and when the motherboard got this functionality or when the manufacturers can add this via a BIOS update - on website like amazon, ebay etc, they don't mention it (except for rare exceptions).

How can I know which motherboards can be used to fully use the built-in hardware encryption of SEDs ?

Comment: Check SED manufacturer site for list of compatible motherboards?

Comment: @Xalorous Can you show an example please ? I've called 2 manufacturer (MSI and Gigabyte) they say themselves they don't have a clue however they have said they will recall me to give me more informations. Related : https://serverfault.com/questions/695495/how-to-find-mainboards-that-supports-self-encrypting-device-sed-in-bios, http://www.tb-kaiser.de/ahci_sbe/

Comment: Basically, there is no need for BIOS support. Please see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/170271/66423.